# selecting specific column on linux terminal

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I used `ls-alhF /` command as an input for `cut` command. Part of `ls-alhF /` output given below. I wanted to select the specific column like second column, or the last column (the one showing the name of file and directories along with link files). I used `cut -d " " -f 2` for it.
To my surprise, it's not working because its taking single space as a delimiter. Because of this, I cant able to perform the last column selection, where

```
drwxr-xr-x 127 root root  12K Dec 24 16:28 etc/
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4.0K Nov  9 18:56 home/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    7 Nov  9 18:50 lib -> usr/lib/
```

is single information column for me. The second line, `lib -> usr/lib/`, cut command considering it as 3 fields ("`lib`", "`->`", "`usr/lib`"). I also tried using `tr`, `column`, `sed`, `grep`; but I'm not getting any desired result.

Help me with this please.

Comment: `I used la-alhF / command as an input for cut command` But why? `I wanted to select the specific column like second column` What is that you "really" want to print? The symlink destinations? You want to print data in the format like directories on separate lines optionally followed by `->` and symlink destination?

Comment: Please include this in your considerations: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: Awk is able to help you.

Comment: Instead of 'cut -d -f', use 'cut -c'.

Comment: I suspect an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you actually trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: @PaulHodges wanted to know how the selection of specific column works. So I used cut command for it, to select last column, i.e., file/dir/link names. But for symlinks representation, their own delimiter is being used to break themselves.

Comment: `ls` shouldn't be selected or parsed **at all**; there are other ways to collect file metadata.

Comment: With GNU find: `find / -maxdepth 1 -type l -printf "%f -> %l\n"`. Take a look at `man find`.

Answer (score 2):

`ls` is generally not a good contender for parsing. Read the [excellent question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead) pointed out by @Cyrus.

For just getting the information about files and their symlinks, `GNU stat` should work.

```sh
stat -f "%N%SY" ./*

# Sample output :
# ./test.py
# ./test.sh -> test.bash
```

which gives me files in my current directory along with those which have symlinks, if any. Multiple other excellent solutions are available [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/173898/only-show-the-source-file-and-target-linked-file-using-ls).

Regarding your question regarding how selection is working, it's separating them into separate columns based on the delimiter you specified. To `cut` or `awk`, it's just a blob of text to work on and nothing special like "output of ls".